# Select from tables depend on row value

Tags: mysql

I would like to select data from 2 tables and the 2nd table is specified by a value stored in a 3rd table.
My tables are:

1. users
2. user_type
3. Could be one of 5 tables (admins, buyers, sellers, accountants, deliverymen)

The required query (Which I don't how to achieve it) must:

I. Select a user from users table where `_id` equals some id.

II. We get the `user_type` (which is int value refers to user_type.type_id) field value (This table has `type_id` and names of the tables e.g. ["1"=>"buyers", "2"=>"sellers", ...])

III. Now we now what is the user type and the table name which contains more info about this user

IV. Select from the table (buyers, sellers, admins, ...) and retrieve the whole data (From table users and the other table (buyers, sellers, admins, ...etc) depending on user type) where table.user_id = users_id

I hope the flow makes sense and thank you (Any suggestions or alternative flows would be much appreciated)

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: well you should be having a table where `user_id` and `type_id` mapping should be there.

Comment: Does the 5 tables have the same structure?

Comment: @Jagrati The `users` table has column type_id

Comment: @Mak No every table has different structure (depends on the entity attributes)

Comment: @hemoali, don't even think of doing the whole work in a single query. Create a procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Mak, I was able to implement the needed functionality as following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getUserData`(IN `user_id` INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE userTypeID INT;
DECLARE userTypeTableName TEXT;
    SELECT user_type into userTypeID FROM users WHERE users._id = user_id LIMIT 1;
    SELECT name into userTypeTableName FROM user_type WHERE user_type.type_id = userTypeID LIMIT 1;
    SET @sql_text = concat('select user.*, sp_user.* from users user JOIN ',userTypeTableName,' sp_user ON user._id = sp_user.user_id WHERE user._id = ', user_id);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the table name from this query.

```
table name = select `type_name` from user_type inner join users on user_type.type_id = users.type_id where users.id = anyId.
```

Then select data from this table

```
select * from table_name where user_id = anyId
```